# dotnet blazor maui google authentication unable to redirect to the mobile app after signing in

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, google-oauth, maui

I am trying to create a google authentication in dotnet blazor maui following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?tabs=android&view=net-maui-7.0).

This is what i am doing

**In google developer console**

[image]

[image]

**1) Creating web application and getting client id and client secret.**

**2) and then creating dot net core web api with this code**

```
[Route("mobileauth")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    const string callbackScheme = "cflow";

    [HttpGet("{scheme}")]
    public async Task Get([FromRoute] string scheme)
    {
        var auth = await Request.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(scheme);

        if (!auth.Succeeded
            || auth?.Principal == null
            || !auth.Principal.Identities.Any(id => id.IsAuthenticated)
            || string.IsNullOrEmpty(auth.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token")))
        {
            // Not authenticated, challenge
            await Request.HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(scheme);
        }
        else
        {
            var claims = auth.Principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault()?.Claims;
            var email = string.Empty;
            email = claims?.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;

            // Get parameters to send back to the callback
            var qs = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "access_token", auth.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token") },
                { "refresh_token", auth.Properties.GetTokenValue("refresh_token") ?? string.Empty },
                { "expires_in", (auth.Properties.ExpiresUtc?.ToUnixTimeSeconds() ?? -1).ToString() },
                { "email", email }
            };

            // Build the result url
            var url = callbackScheme + "://#" + string.Join(
                "&",
                qs.Where(kvp => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Value) && kvp.Value != "-1")
                .Select(kvp => $"{WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key)}={WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value)}"));

            // Redirect to final url
            Request.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url);
        }
    }
}
```

**3)program.cs in web api is**

[image]

**going into dotnet maui blazor app this is the android manifest code**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="mazhar.mazhar">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
    </intent>
  </queries>
```

**4)This is mainactivity.cs file code**

[image]

The webauthenticator code is

```
    async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        var scheme = "Google";
        var authUrlRoot = "https://webapisss.azurewebsites.net/mobileauth/";
        WebAuthenticatorResult r = null;


        var authUrl = new Uri($"{authUrlRoot}{scheme}");
        var callbackUrl = new Uri("cflow://");

        r = await WebAuthenticator.Default.AuthenticateAsync(authUrl, callbackUrl);
    

        string AuthToken = r?.AccessToken ?? r?.IdToken // it should redirect here which is not happening;
        //Debug.WriteLine(AuthToken);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //AuthToken = string.Empty;
    //  Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        await DisplayAlert("Cflow", $"Failed: {ex.Message}", "OK");
    }
}
```

**Any idea why Redirect back to the mobile app not happening after this ? and in the next screen it is asking for permission and then 404 error**

[image]

That is my question how do i resolve this 404 error? how it is going to be redirected back to my mobile application.I think that the answer lies in the callbackscheme. I need to mention it somewhere

According to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCPENg5wP8o) video web authenticator worked in xamarin forms but it is also giving redirect issue? any workable idea in dotnet maui and xamarin ?

Comment: so the google call is made correctly and it fails after that? did you make sure that the redirect url https://webapisss.azurewebsites.net/signin-google is correct?

Comment: it ask for the permission of webapisss then it fails giving 404 error

Comment: Yes the google sign button appears and then after signing in it ask for the permission. i allow it then it should be redirected again to the mobile app. it give 404 error on next screen

Comment: Well did you try to access the url? nothing is happening if I try to access it. might be a dumb question but I'm not really familiar with MAUI and the google sign in stuff.

Comment: this is the url https://webapisss.azurewebsites.net/mobileauth/Google

Comment: in your google config you are telling google to make a redirect to this address https://webapisss.azurewebsites.net/signin-google which in fact returns a 404.

Comment: this is the first screen it hits https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?response_type=code&client_id=115254485184-5uec80t8aa0nghdnhv63ts7aur0mdfr2.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwebapisss.azurewebsites.net%2Fsignin-google&scope=openid%20profile%20email&state=CfDJ8ACY1bRac7hDgCUgdoiSCchTsZD8DA1RGJPQwZxcqiCZdYT2YX50IBZhOoebYP3Azk9EUdSkKv0hURpuCbx_SbpTUJGQ_IirSYG_SyWi8ZFqP-WROt5Im0r1CfyLyC5a6jDyiawQ5aVB3RUZKN-uUOMezdzpf77_o4vyfhFLeSieM6Zx_hQnG-HRzLGFCPTFvKDK7GZCjwKn02u4ReixoTls3EeoTWVnXeddjWbA0XlX&service=lso&o2v=2&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

Comment: yes, I understand that. But you are doing a redirect AFTER you successfully logged in to a URL which doesnt exist. therefore you get the 404 error. https://webapisss.azurewebsites.net/signin-google this link is not valid and thus returns a 404

Comment: thatis my question how do i resolve this 404 error? how it is going to be redirected back to my mobile application. i think that answer lies in the redirect uri in google console but i dont't know about it.

Comment: i think that the answer lies in the callbackscheme. i need to mention it somewhere

Comment: you resolve the error by redirecting to a valid URL.

Comment: how can i do that? it should be redirected to the access token line in the code mobile

Comment: In your google console where you specified the authorized redirect URI please change it to this: https://webapisss.azurewebsites.net/mobileauth/Google and see what happens.

Comment: To which url it redirects when you get 404?

Comment: webapisss.azurewebsites.net

Comment: I'd agree with Aaron - you tell google to redirect to signin-google, but your server expects mobileauth/google url. So signin-google gives 404.

Comment: adding it in google developer console give me No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:7041/signin-google?state=CfDJ8Nv5TT7XMk1NrAe0fc4RT3ohIzFEt6YlRck-1l1DqTfrHMJLU7Of7BEWcIn3AyuxqeiznqtjLJW-Vj_MMOWb2RqJRXTDw8EiuRfqXhBGgNpaKYgCPnGCO2a6BkWRfc7HOrWPIsTg9ikrgLGExZ8Up1BckxyeTrzNDDPBDQlqJj3Q4RVwq3oAPeQacn2iTk_TrwbNjn8nqV3LxLTY9GEP-l_InfvLRvXHKUhNrc5UnK7P&code=4%2F0AWgavdeFtLgpIdgBnhxLvNpSKp-fXUQJwM9Fdiv7x3j-ipw8M5HqwTOZFAjbexPgY-

Comment: What's this localhost:7041 url, where did it come from? I meant to put https://webapisss.azurewebsites.net/mobileauth/Google as your redirect url in google console.

Comment: No its my local url same as this webapisss.azurewebsites.net/mobileauth/Google

Comment: playing around i have been successfully calling the second response method in the api now. any idea how can i successfully authenticate this method   var auth = await Request.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(scheme) in my second response call in the api;

Comment: This is the response method webapisss.azurewebsites.net/mobileauth/Google

Comment: webapisss.azurewebsites.net/mobileauth/Google  will not work without giving /mobileauth/Google in g.callback in program.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is consumed on the client side successfully with information returned

[image]

Appart from the code above two things were added

first

[image]

second

this callback was added here

```
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
            .AddCookie()
            .AddGoogle(g =>
            {
                g.ClientId = "htcgb9jg7qs0o5r7skn9k2nuq46ps1so";
                g.ClientSecret = "lyl"; 
                g.CallbackPath = "/mobileauth";
                g.SaveTokens = true;

            });
```

Comment: I have a question. How are you going to verify the app if you are using that reidrect uri?  Have you checked that its allowed normally you need to be the owner of the domain you are using when setting the app to production.     You cant azurewebsites.net in google search console.

Comment: I think that these configuration will work in the production

Comment: if you think otherwise i can have a test check of it on my personal domain

Comment: I mean when you apply for [verficiaton](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en)  after your app has been set to production on the consent screen in google cloud console.    Let me know what they say about that redirect uri.   I would love to take it up with the team if they refuse it.

Comment: ok i will have a look through the link

Comment: I reached out to someone at google.   About that redirect uri.   The authorized domain has to be a top private domain.  More details in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/production-readiness/brand-verification#authorized-domains)
One option you may have is to [associate a custom domain name](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/associating-a-custom-domain-name-and-securing-communication-with-azure-0eeba4ff-3432-e59a-7f7a-0ee8c7cd7c11) with the their azure website which they can then use as the authorized domain.    Let me know how it goes.