Error The “VerifyVersionsTask” task failed unexpectedly
I have Created new Maui Projct Everything was working fine until i Installed latest version of xamarin.Auth version v1.7.0
`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  MSB4018 The "VerifyVersionsTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.NugetPackages.GatherProjectJsonVersions(String packageIdPrefix, String projectExtensionsPath, IEnumerable`1 excludedPackages, Version monoandroidVersion, Dictionary`2 packageVersions, TaskLoggingHelper log)
   at Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.VerifyVersionsTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() EcommerceDemo (net8.0-android)  C:\Users\r\.nuget\packages\xamarin.android.support.annotations\28.0.0.1\build\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.targets 17  `

I have checked some other thing about this error on internet & I alredy have package version of 28.0.0.1
so thats not the problem..
removing that xamarin.auth is resolving my problem but i really need it for google sign..
 `private async void GoogleSignInButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
           clientId: GoogleClientId,
           scope: "email",
           authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"),
           redirectUrl: new Uri("test"));

       auth.Completed += OnAuthCompleted;
       auth.Error += OnAuthError;

       var presenter = new Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter();
       presenter.Login(auth);
   }`


The xamarin.auth doesn't support for Maui. And you can use the Web authenticator instead.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT ah thanks...

@LiyunZhang-MSFT Can you help me with that.. I have tried that but i dont know how to get or what to do with it new uri somethich with myap//
i even see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73605588/correct-way-to-use-web-authenticator-in-net-maui-for-google-login-on-android
but there are also some queries about it i mean how i suppose to get url in android app in google console credentials??
i did some googl
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/643111/how-to-make-google-and-facebook-auth-in-net-maui?page=1&orderby=Helpful&comment=answer-1534506#newest-answer-comment

@DevelopmentTeam The second URI parameter myapp:// is not a valid URI, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72641363/net-maui-webauthenticator-callbackurl-for-social-logins and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75161015/dotnet-blazor-maui-google-authentication-unable-to-redirect-to-the-mobile-app-af
